# Continuous bijection to Hausdorff is homeomorphism $\Rightarrow$ compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

There is a famous theorem that for a compact topological space $X$, continuous bijection $f:X\to Y $ where $Y$ is Hausdorff is homeomorphic.

I want to know if the converse is true, i.e.

Let topological sapce $X$ satisfy the following property:

> For any continuous bijection $f:X\to Y $ where $Y$ is Hausdorff is homeomorphic.

Then,  can we say $X$ is compact?

For example, if $X=(0,1]$ then let $Y$ be a circle and continuous bojection $f:X\to Y$ be connecting $1\in X$ to $0\notin X$, so we fail to construct counterexample.
If $X=(0,1)$ then connect $0\notin X$ to $\frac{1}{2}\in X$.

Comment: You mean the convers.. ? Not inverse, inverse of if P then Q is if NOT P, then NOT Q.. youre asking if youre given a conitnuous bijection with range space Hausdorff, is it always the case that the domain is compact?

Comment: I wanna say let $X=\Bbb{R}^+$ and $Y=\Bbb{R}$ and take $f(x):=\ln (x)$.. this may be a counter-example? It is clear to see $\Bbb{R}^+$ is *not* compact..unless I'm missing something here, since my $f$ is 1-1, onto, continuous, the reals are Hausdorff and the positive reals aren't compact.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, and thank you for your edit. 
 I used the "converse" in the sense as follow. property P :$X$ is compact. property Q : for all Hausdorff $Y$ and cont bije $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is homeo.

Comment: +1 upvote for your curiosity.. I had a prof once who always said a good mathematician is a stubborn mathematician as in one who only believes something if they can prove it or understand a proof of it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then we have a new topology on $X$ generated by subsets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$ over open subsets $U\subseteq Y$. This topology is coarser than that of $X$, and $f$ (seen as a map onto its image) is a quotient map under this topology.

So if $f$ is bijective and a quotient map than it is a homeomorphism. Under the new topology of course. So your question can be restated as:

> Given a minimal Hausdorff space, is it compact?

Here "minimal" means coarsest among Hausdorff topologies. Note that a compact Hausdorff space indeed is minimal.

The answer to that question is "no". In other words there is a non-compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that every continuous bijection starting at $X$ onto a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. A concrete example can be found in the famous *Counterexamples in Topology* book, part II, counterexample 100. Also see this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36085/minimal-hausdorff

Comment: Do you assume  existence of some continuous bijection $f:X\to Y$ ?

Comment: @Yos there might not exist a bijection (continuous or not) at all between two spaces. What you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood a little. However, I have solved the problem and understand your answer. Thank you.